# How Recode values in R from SPSS .sav file which contain NA?

Tags: r, match, spss, recode

`enter code here`I have a SPSS data, loaded using haven package, which I need to change values 0-4 to 4-0 in several columns called here as "tss" in the data psychophobia (psychophobia$tss1, psychophobia$tss2...), creating a new column as recodtss... additionally, there are several NAs data.

[image]

I´ve tried this code:

```
old <- 0:4
new <- c(4:0)
psychophobia$Recodtss01 <- psychophobia$tss01[psychophobia$tss01 %in% old] <-new[match(psychophobia$tss01,old,nomatch = "NA")]
psychophobia$Recodtss02 <- psychophobia$tss01[psychophobia$tss02 %in% old] <-new[match(psychophobia$tss02,old,nomatch = "NA")]
```

The problem is that the current output is

> psychophobia$tss01
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqtPh.png)  4  1  1 NA NA  3  2  0  1

> psychophobia$Recodtss01
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqtPh.png)  4  1  1 NA  3  2  0  1  2

Can anyone help to understand why? :)

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible data. You could copy/paste the output of `dput(psychophobia)` to your post.

Comment: tss05 = structure(c(3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 4, 1, 0, 3, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, NA, 3, 3, NA, 4, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 4, 3, 0, 
    1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3), label = "tratamento psicologico", format.spss = "F8.2", labels = c(`Discordo fortemente` = 0, 
    Discordo = 1, `Não concordo nem discordo` = 2, Concordo = 3, 
    `Concordo fortemente` = 4), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
    "double"))

Comment: I´ve updated the post with a small table of the dataframe

Comment: The simplest way to convert 0:4 to 4:0 is `Recodtss05 <- 4 - tss05`, although this drops the information of labels.

Comment: I cannot believe it is that simple... thank you soo much

Comment: @DarrenTsai how can I create a loop for this?

     for (i in 01:28){
  psychophobia$Recodtss[i] <- 4 - psychophobia$tss[i]}

Comment: `for (i in 1:28) { psychophobia[[sprintf("Recodtss%02d", i)]] <- 4 - psychophobia[[sprintf("tss%02d", i)]] }`

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with SPSS, the package https://strengejacke.github.io/sjmisc/reference/rec.html might help you. The syntax is more elaborate, but safe and easy to read.

```
table(rec(psychophobia$Recodtss01, rec = "1=4;2=3;3=2;4=1;NA=9"), useNA = "always")
```

or with dplyr

```
psychophobia %>%
   mutate(Recodetss01 = sjmisc::rec(Recodetss01, rec = "1=4;2=3;3=2;4=1;NA=9"))
```